# How to add paginate to laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and I am having error in adding paginate using laravel eloquent.

This code work without `paginate()`. If paginate was added, got error

> Method paginate does not exist.

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->findOrFail([1,2,3,4,5])
            ->where('status','p')
            ->paginate(7);
```

Comment: Have you tried $articles = Article::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4,5])
            ->where('status','p')
            ->paginate(7);

Comment: Do not use paginate with findOrFail !!

Comment: findOrFail will return a collection and collection have no pagination

Comment: Thanks pseudoanime :-) your code work and thanks to other for teaching me

Answer (score 1):

As people have mentioned in the comments, you can not use `findOrFail()` with `paginate()` since they are both ways to execute a query. You can instead use [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses).

To get what you're after you can do:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4,5]) //assuming "id" is the primary key for the table
            ->where('status','p')
            ->paginate(7);
```